# Skobbler Android SDK: How to add more language files

Tags: android, skmaps

I am trying to use a different audio advice language for navigation, however when I set the `SKAdvisorSettings` to use a new language (en_us) it said it could not find the file. After some research I found this link saying I needed to add the sound files to the `.zip` file:

http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7250-Language-files-for-2-5-0-and-2-5-1

However when I unzip, add the file, and zip again (using Mac, right click, compress), the map fails to initialize and the only error shown is `E/SKPrepareMapTextureThread: Shaders or Common files not found`

Maybe I do not know how to add files to a `.zip` without otherwise affecting it, or I am missing how I am supposed to add the sound files to the project completely.

tl;dr: I want to be able to add more sound files to the navigation advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have added the language files, you have to create a new zip by selecting all files **inside** the SKMaps folder, and renamed it from Archive.zip to SKMaps.zip and move it the assets folder replacing the old SKMaps.zip.